# Exclude title from display not working

Tags: 7, theming, entities, webforms

I want to hide the titles of the webform by using [Exclude form display](https://www.drupal.org/project/exclude_node_title) module.
I installed and given permission for anonymous user to use it. For all webform I am having a common template file that is webform-form.tpl.php. In this template file I am printing the title of the webform like below

```
print $form['#node']->title;
```

I thought because of this the module is not working, So i decided to check the checkbox of Exclude title from display is checked or not in this template file. I am not getting `exclude_node_title` varibale in my template file. So please help me to get this in template file.

Answer (score 0):

I've not gone in detail of the module code, but from brief overview it seems that module doesn't define any variable at template level. You can check if you're able to access `$node->exclude_node_title` variable in template file. If not, then to hide a node title, you can call `_exclude_node_title()` function which determine whether the node title should be excluded. Check the example usage of `_exclude_node_title()` function in `_exclude_node_title_preprocess()` function.

```
/**
 * Remove the title from the variables array.
 * NOTE : Example usage from module.
 */
function _exclude_node_title_preprocess(&$vars, $node, $view_mode) {
  // If node title needs to be excluded from display.
  if (_exclude_node_title($node, $view_mode)) {
    $vars['title'] = '';
    if ($view_mode == 'nodeform') {
      // Prevent access to the title field on nodeform view mode.
      $vars['page']['content']['system_main']['title']['#access'] = FALSE;
    }
  }
}
```